# Problem in understanding broadcast receiver

Tags: android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I have an app in which I'm trying to detect *WHEN* the Internet connection appears and when it disappears.

At the moment, when it appears, I'm starting a new thread (different from the UI) which connects my app to a remote server.

For that I'm hardly trying to implement a broadcast receiver which *LISTENS* for connectivity, but I'm having problems in understanding the concept.

In my `onCreate()` I have somethig like:

```
onCreate()    
{
     cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread(syncToken));
     cThread.start();
}
```

When there is connection to the Internet I'm sending data through the socket, when there is not I'm storing the data in a database. And when the Internet appears I'm restarting my thread to reconnect and send the old data (which hasn't been sent because of network crashing) and the new one.

Let's say I would implement something like this:

```
DoRefreshBroadcastReceiver refreshBroadcastReceiver; 
...    
onResume() {    
  // register the refreshing complete broadcast receiver    
  IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DO_REFRESH);    
  refreshBroadcastReceiver = new doRefreshBroadcastReceiver();    
  registerReceiver(refreshBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);        
}

public class DoRefreshBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {     
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    
        // call method to run fetch code...
    }
}
```

Does this mean that when the Internet connection is detected my `onReceive()` gets called? And I could start my thread there?

What is the concept of using an intent? Because I really don't get it. How to use it, and what its purpose?

---

THE IDEA: I don't really know how to use this intent in this case or how to use it in my app!

Would this thing detect the connection to the Internet even when I'm not in this activity?

---

EDIT:

Here is how my onReceive looks like:

---

```
onCreate()
{
    cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread(syncToken));
    // cThread.start();

    connIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                             "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
    connListener = new MyConnectivityListener();
}
```

---

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    mNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
            .getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

    if (mNetworkInfo != null && mNetworkInfo.isConnected())
    {
        /*
         * if(mNetworkInfo.getType()==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
         *
         *
         * else
         */

        cThread.start();
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("There is no internet connection!");

        try {
            cThread.stop();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
mNetworkInfo != null && mNetworkInfo.isConnected()
```

Does this mean it's connected or should I verify for a certain type of connection on the emulator?

*I think that I should start my thread directly in `onReceive()`. As soon as my app starts it detects the Internet connection and `BroadcastReceiver` gets fired, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm asking for too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MyConnectivityListener connListener = null;
    private IntentFiler connIntentFilter = null;
    private Boolean connIntentFilterIsRegistered = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(...) {
        ...
        connIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        connListener = new MyConnectivityListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        ...
        if (!connIntentFilterIsRegistered) {
            registerReceiver(connListener, connIntentFilter);
            connIntentFilterIsRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        ...
        if (connIntentFilterIsRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(connListener);
            connIntentFilterIsRegistered = false;
        }
    }

    protected class MyConnectivityListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // The NetworkInfo for the affected network is sent
            // as an extra; it should be consulted to see what
            // kind of connectivity event occurred.
        }
    }
}
```

A BroadcastReceiver is effectively a 'listener' which listens for events either sent by the system or, in some cases, by your own application components.

In this case, the system broadcasts `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` whenever there is a connection change (connected/disconnected). By registering your BroadcastReceiver to 'listen' for that event, you can get the `extra` included in the Intent from your BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive(...)` method and do whatever you need to do accordingly. The extra is a `NetworkInfo object which will contain information about the particular network and whether it is connected or not.

Comment: If I put this connIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"); in my onCreate() is this  the thing that tells my broadcast when the state of the network changes??? I don't need something else ...? Secondly,in onReceive() I verify what kind of connection is...and if is WiFi or something like it means that I could restart my thread...ya???.....And if is connected and is good could I start my thread in onReceive()????Or how this part of restarting of the thread works???Thank u for clearing up the things a little bit more:)

Comment: @george: The bit in onCreate() is simply there to initialize connIntentFilter with the name of the 'event' you want to listen out for. You then pass it to `registerReceiver(...)` along with the instance of your BroadcastReceiver. By registering, you tell the system that you want to be notified of a connection change. By checking the NetworkInfo in onReceive you can tell if the 'event' is a connection or disconnection so start/stop your thread accordingly.

Comment: Could you please take a look on the edit on my question,a few last questions:D!Thank u a lot

Comment: @george: I think you're pretty much there. To answer one question - no, the receiver won't continue to work once you leave your Activity if you implement the code in my example for unregistering the receiver in onPause() (which is recommended). If you need it to work at all times then things get more complicated. I suggest you experiment with it as it is now and get to know some more about how BroadcastReceivers and Intent broadcasts work.

Comment: If I start my app and I have internet connection it connects to  the remote server but if I remove the internet connection It won't display any System.out.println() .....or not reconnect to my remote server